# $N\trianglelefteq G$, $A$ a conjugacy class in $G$ such that $A\subseteq N$, prove $A$ is a union of conjugacy classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

> $N\trianglelefteq G$. Now let $A$ be a conjugacy class in $G$ such that $A\subseteq N$.
>
> - Prove $A$ is a union of conjugacy classes in $N$ and they all have the same size.
> - Denote this number of classes as $k$, now prove $k=[G:C_G(x)N]$ for each $x\in A$.

This question alreay appears on stackexchange but my proof seems different. (Or perhaps I just wrote it down in to much detail) *Is the following correct*?

#### First statement

Choose an $x$ in $N$ and let $A=\{x^g: g\in G\} = x^G$ be a conjugacy class in $G$.

Now let $N$ act on $A$ by conjugation, such that $(x^g)^n = x^{gn}$. Notice how this element is once again an element of $A$.

Now consider the orbits resulting from this action. These orbits partition $A$ so $A$ is a union of conjugacy classes in $N$. Now we prove that they have the same size

Choose a $x^g$ and $x^h \in A$. I wish to show $|(x^g)^N|=|(x^h)^N|$. By the orbit-stabilizer formula
$$
|N| = |N_{x^g}| \cdot |(x^g)^N| \qquad |N| = |N_{x^h}|\cdot |(x^h)^N|.
$$

Since $N_{x^g} = g^{-1}N_x g$ and $N_{x^h} = h^{-1}N_x h$ it follows that $|N_{x^g}| = |N_{x^h}|$. Because $\iota_g, \iota_h\in \mathrm{Inn}(N)$, this implies $|(N_x)^g| = |N_x| = |(N_x)^h|$. Then this results in $|(x^g)^N| = |(x^h)^N|$.

#### Second statement

Here [Conjugacy class of $G$ splitting as Conjugacy class of $H\unlhd G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623172/conjugacy-class-of-g-splitting-as-conjugacy-class-of-h-unlhd-g) seems to provide adequate inspiration.